# Column name seems to be use instead of alias in GROUP BY

Tags: postgresql

For a project, I'm looking to get all results group by day.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS id, 
       SUM(value) AS value, 
       country, 
       cast(TO_CHAR(date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS DATE) AS date 
FROM records 
GROUP BY date, country
```

My problem is that records are not groupped correctly when I use my "date" alias, instead it seems to group by the field name.

Results with group by alias

[image: Results with group by alias]

It works if I use indices instead of alias, but I'd like to have column's name in my result :

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS id, 
       SUM(value) AS value, 
       country, 
       cast(TO_CHAR(date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS DATE) AS date 
FROM records 
GROUP BY 3, 4
```

Results with group by indices

[image: Results with group by indices]

Has someone an idea why it works this way?

Comment: Unrelated, but: if `date` is a `timestamp` you can also use `date::date` to remove the time part of the timestamp

Comment: What is wrong with the second version, which seems to solve your problem?

Comment: Yeah, it works, but I'd like to understand why it doesn't work in the first version !

Answer (score 0):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY)

> An expression used inside a grouping_element can be an input column name, or the name or ordinal number of an output column (SELECT list item), or an arbitrary expression formed from input-column values. **In case of ambiguity, a GROUP BY name will be interpreted as an input-column name rather than an output column name**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So the (input) column names always have precedence over column aliases.

Answer (score 0):

The two `GROUP BY` clauses are not equivalent.

In both, the `SELECT` clause is:

```sql
SELECT
    MAX(id) AS id, 
    SUM(value) AS value, 
    country, 
    cast(TO_CHAR(date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS DATE) AS date
```

So the columns will be (`id`, `value`, `country`, `date`).

The first query groups by `date` then `country`:

```sql
GROUP BY date, country
```

The second groups by `country` then `date`:

```sql
GROUP BY 3, 4
```

With different hierarchy of `GROUP BY` you'll get different results, such as what you show.